# Как скопировать слова между определенными символами?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо выполнить команду в каждой папке почтового сервера. В выдаче получил список папок. На сколько я разобрался, имя папки находится между символами "/" " и "'
Но что то у меня не как не получается собрать эти имена в список:( 
Пробовал шаманить с модулем re, что то не чего не получается:(

```
import re

string = """('OK', [b'(\\Inbox) "/" "INBOX"', b'() "/" "&BCIENQRBBEIEPgQyBEsENQ- &BEIENQQ7BDUEMwRABDAEPAQ8BEs-"', b'(\\Spam) "/" "&BCEEPwQwBDw-"', b'(\\Sent) "/" "&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"', b'(\\Drafts) "/" "&BCcENQRABD0EPgQyBDgEOgQ4-"', b'(\\Trash) "/" "&BBoEPgRABDcEOAQ9BDA-"', b'(\\NoInferiors) "/" "INBOX/Social"', b'(\\NoInferiors) "/" "INBOX/News Letters"'])"""

string = re.findall(r'"/" "+\D+"\'', string)

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если внимательно посмотреть, то string это не строка, а кортеж. И тогда регулярка не нужна.

```
string = ('OK', [b'(\\Inbox) "/" "INBOX"', b'() "/" "&BCIENQRBBEIEPgQyBEsENQ- &BEIENQQ7BDUEMwRABDAEPAQ8BEs-"', b'(\\Spam) "/" "&BCEEPwQwBDw-"', b'(\\Sent) "/" "&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"', b'(\\Drafts) "/" "&BCcENQRABD0EPgQyBDgEOgQ4-"', b'(\\Trash) "/" "&BBoEPgRABDcEOAQ9BDA-"', b'(\\NoInferiors) "/" "INBOX/Social"', b'(\\NoInferiors) "/" "INBOX/News Letters"'])

folders = [f.decode('utf-8').split(' "/" ') for f in string[1]]
for fld, path in folders:
    fld = fld.strip('()')
    path = path.strip('"')
    print(fld, path)
```